# How to input decimal in c

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, input, double, decimal

I am trying to input  a decimal in the program, but it is giving me a different output. I have used %5.2f, float and double, and it still not working. I want to calculate the diameter, area and circumference of a circle, but the output is different.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    double radius;
    double pi = 3.14;
    double diameter;
    double area;
    double circumference;

    printf("\t\tEnter value for radius: ");
    scanf_s("%5.2f", &radius);
    printf("radius is %5.2f", radius);

    diameter = radius*2;
    area = pi*(radius*radius);
    circumference = 2*(pi*radius);

    printf("\n\t\tThe diameter of the circle is %d \n", diameter);
    printf("\t\tArea: %d", area);
    printf("\t\tCircumference: %d", circumference);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

please tell me my mistakes,
Also, I tried using M_PI to have a mathematical constant, but it does not work.

Comment: "Not working" is a useless bug report. How is it not working? I suspect that your input works fine, but your output is integral, and that you might wish to change `%d` to `%f` in those `printf` calls, but without a better description of your problem, it's just a blind guess.

Comment: I did, and its giving negative output

Comment: Where is your `main()` function?

Comment: @ABFORCE It is there now.

Comment: If you are using `C++` my recommend is to use `cin` instead of using `scanf()`, By using `cin` you are no longer to bothering with `%5.2f` or something like this

Comment: I am using C, and VS 2010 won't run the program if I did not use scanf_s()

Comment: @eLg: you should not print a `float` variable by `printf("%d",...)` .This causes the number to be round, you should use `printf("%f",...)` instead

Comment: @eLg to limit the number of input items you can specify field width like `scanf_s("%ws",&radius);` where `w` is  the field width as per your choice.

Comment: Printing a `float` variable by `printf("%d"),...)` does not cause the number to be round. It causes the raw bits of the floating-point value to be interpreted as an integer, resulting in complete nonsense. (Additionally, if `float` and `int` are not the same size, it throws off the offset counts, and any further conversions by that `printf()` call will also be complete nonsense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct input format specifier for a `double` is `%lf` (or `%lg` or `%le`).

```
scanf_s("%lf", &radius);
```

When you print it again, you can format it however you want.

```
printf("radius is %5.2f", radius);
```

Comment: @Henrick, I am getting the correct output now. Is there a way to limit the number of decimals?

Comment: Try with `%lg`. `%lf` always gives you six digits of presicion, while `%lg` gives you _up to_ six digits.

Comment: Format specifier for double is `%f` in c99. You are referring to c89.

Comment: @PHIfounder C99 comment referred only to `%la`, not the others. Edited to avoid confusion. Please reconsider downvote.